# What layout on Java I need?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a JPanel and for example, if I click on the button "INSERT", I can add a JButton and a JLabel. My problem is I need to insert the JLabel under the JButton. The JLabel text must centred respect the JButton text. After that, I want a space around 10 pixels to use again my "INSERT" button and add horizontally a new pair on JButton and JLabel with the same orientation.

Thanks!

PD: Please, complement your question with an attempt.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: I think that I should have a design (like screens) before start the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example that shows a dynamic (which is what I assume you wanted) setup to allow insertion of an undefined number of panels:

```
public class AwesomeAnswer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     // please not that this is only an example and not a 
     // Swing thread safe way of starting a JFrame
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();

     JPanel content = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
     // create our top panel that will hold all of the inserted panels
     JPanel page = new JPanel();
     page.setLayout( new BoxLayout( page, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
     // add our page to the frame content pane
     content.add( page );
     // add two button/label panels
     page.add( insert( "This is an awesome answer", "Accept" ) );
     page.add( insert( "Say thank you", "Thank" ) );


     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible( true );
  }

  public static final JPanel insert( String labelText, String buttonText ) {
     // create the label and the button
     JLabel lbl = new JLabel( labelText );
     JButton btn = new JButton( buttonText );
     // create the panel that will hold the label and the button
     JPanel wrapPanel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
     wrapPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 10, 10, 10, 10 ) );
     // tell the grid bag how to behave
     GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
     gbc.gridwidth = 0;
     gbc.gridheight = 2;

     // make the button centered
     JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( 0, 0, FlowLayout.CENTER ) );
     buttonPanel.add( btn );

     // make the label centered
     JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( 0, 0, FlowLayout.CENTER ) );
     labelPanel.add( lbl );

     // add our button and label to the grid bag with our constraints
     wrapPanel.add( buttonPanel, gbc );
     wrapPanel.add( labelPanel, gbc );

     return wrapPanel;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have something like that

```
rootPane
    +-----panelButton
    |            +------JButton
    |
    +-----panelPanels
              +-----panel
                     +---JButton
                     +---JLabel
```

The `SpringLayout` can help you

```
SpringUtilities.makeGrid(panel,
                     2, 1, //rows, cols
                     0, 0, //initialX, initialY
                     5, 5);//xPad, yPad
```

Comment: I'll try this alternative. Thank you for your answer!